# JavaScriptとPerlで、ファイルをドラッグ&ドロップしたらアップロード

Tags: javascript, html5, perl

JavaScriptとPerlで、ファイルをドラッグ&ドロップしたら、サーバにファイルをアップロードする仕組みを作りたいです。

「Ajaxを利用して複数画像をドラッグ＆ドロップで一括アップロード」
http://qiita.com/uda0922/items/4e22908ce2acb3a28f29

などを見ながら作ってみたのですが、うまくいきません。無反応です。

Perlの該当関数

```
sub UploadFiles(){
    my @files = $q->param('upload');
    foreach my $file(@files){
        my $tmp = $q->tmpFileName($file);
        $file = basename($file);
        my $path = ".";
        my $newfile = "$path/$file";
        copy($tmp, $newfile);
        $newfile = decode('UTF-8', $newfile);

        $err .= $newfile . "をアップロードしました。";
    }
}
```

フォーム部分

```
<form name = "form" action = "./sfs.cgi" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<p>
<input type = "file" name = "upload" size = "100" multiple />
<button type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "upload">アップロード</button>
</p>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// File APIに対応していない場合はエリアを隠す
if (!window.File) {
    document.getElementById('image_upload_section').style.display = "none";
}

// ブラウザ上でファイルを展開する挙動を抑止
function onDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

// Drop領域にドロップした際のファイルのプロパティ情報読み取り処理
function onDrop(event) {
    // ブラウザ上でファイルを展開する挙動を抑止
    event.preventDefault();

    // ドロップされたファイルのfilesプロパティを参照
    var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        // 一件ずつアップロード
        imageFileUpload(files[i]);
    }
}

// ファイルアップロード
function imageFileUpload(f) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', f);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: './sfs.cgi',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("ok!");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

有識者の方、ご教示いただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: 開発者ツールでの応答状況およびWebサーバーのアクセスログはどうなっているのでしょうか？ 「うまくいきません。無反応です。」では誰も何もわからないかと。

Comment: ウェブサーバのアクセスログには記録されていない模様です。
javascript 初心者のため、開発者ツールとはなんでしょうか? と聞いてしまうぐらいです。
ネットで調べると数が多すぎて、どれが開発者ツールの解説としていいのかわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

コードを見た感じではたぶん現状では、ファイルをドラッグアンドドロップしてもそのファイルが開かれるだけかと思います。

サンプルと指定されているコードはAjaxでファイルをPOSTするプログラムのようなのでFormタグは不要ですね。
ファイルをドロップするための領域をDIVなどで用意して、 その領域に対してイベントハンドラの「ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondrop="onDrop(event)"」をサンプルの通りに設定してあげてください。
見た感じではこれで動くと思います。

ファイルをドラッグアンドドロップしてもそのイベントを受け取るようにイベントハンドラが設定されていないのが原因でしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
今週末に見直してみます。
取り急ぎのコメントにて失礼します。